# Setting the Location-Attribute of a UserControl does not update the y-Value

Tags: c#, winforms, location, autoscroll

I've got a `UserControl` (winforms) that is placed onto a Form (actually a `Weifen.Luo.DockContent`, that again derives from the basic form). `AutoScroll` is enabled for the form and the control can be moved on it by dragging around (more precisely by evaluating `MouseDown`, `MouseMove`, `MouseUp` and updating the `Location`).

Sometimes* when reaching the border (so that the form's plane must be further enlarged) updating the location of the control suddenly stops working; setting `Location = ..` fails. For demonstration a snippet from the immediate window while debugging:

```
>Location
{X = 50 Y = 751}
    IsEmpty: false
    X: 50
    x: 50
    Y: 751
    y: 751
```

But after updating...

```
>Location = new Point(30, 40);
>Location
{X = 30 Y = 751}
    IsEmpty: false
    X: 30
    x: 30
    Y: 751
    y: 751
```

.. the y-Value still remains the same. How can this be? It seems as there is an LocationChanged-Handler attached (outside user code) thats works against me. Any hints?

*) allthough I wasn't able to find the exact cases when it happens, I found ways to reproduce it, e.g. when focusing a textbox on the control and then moving it to the edge or adding an (empty!) `Load` event handler to the control - weird. I know this sounds more like a race condition. But currently I've got no idea where to go on searching.

---

Update: Every time the update fails, the Parent-Form's `AutoScrollPosition` gets updated instead, resulting so that *delta(AutoScrollPosition before and after) = delta(Location, newValueForLocation)*.